# Find an equation of a plane normal to a given vector

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I have to find an equation for a plane normal to the vector $\vec{r(t)} = \langle e^{t}sin(\frac{\pi t}{2}),e^{t}cos(\frac{\pi t}{2}),t^{2}\rangle$ when $t=1$. I know I have to find the derivative and then plug in the value for t such that $\vec{r'(1)}$, then use each coordinate of the point with this vector to determine an equation. But since I don't have a point I don't know how to proceed. What is the best way to tackle this?

Comment: You need to find the plane passing through $r(1)$ that is perpendicular to the vector $r'(1)$. I am guessing that you meant $r$, not $r'$ above?

Comment: oops. yes. sorry about that.

Comment: I am still not clear on how to find this since you simply restated the question. All of the examples in the book give a known point to start with. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what point you are looking for. The point $r(1) = (e,0,1)$ is on the plane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation is $r'(1) \centerdot ((x,y,z) - r(1)) = 0 $

Comment: I see. r(1) itself is the point. That makes sense now.